# Is there an equivalent of python enumerate in Stata?

Tags: stata

In python, one can loop over a list of values and access their respective indexes using enumerate. For example:

```py
values=['var2006','var2007','var2008','var2009','var2010','var2011']


for index, value in enumerate(values, start=1):
    print(value.replace(value[-4:],str(index)))
```

Which returns:

```
var1
var2
var3
var4
var5
var6
```

I would like to do something similar in Stata. Specifically, I have a list of variables like `'var2006','var2007','var2008','var2009','var2010','var2011'` and I would like to rename them to `'var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6'`. I'm trying to use a combination of `foreach` and `rename` but if there is something similar to python enumerate it will solve this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the rename command with the renumber and sort options:

```
rename var# var#, renumber sort
```

Alternatively, if you want to refer to each variable individually, you could also use forvalues loop and a local macro. This would be more similar to Python's enumerate as you could refer to one variable at a time:

```
clear
set obs 100

gen var2006 = 1
gen var2007 = 2
gen var2008 = 3
gen var2009 = 4
gen var2010 = 5
gen var2011 = 6

forvalues i = 2006/2011 {
    local j = `i' - 2005
    rename var`i' var`j'
}
```

Note that the local macro `j` is equal to the year minus 2005, and you could set this to be any number to change the names of the variables.